# No such module was linked: electron_common_features - Electron react test failing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, electron

I created a react electron app from [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate). And installed the [`@electron/remote`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote) package. Also changed the test case. Now when I run `npm test` it says `No such module was linked: electron_common_features`. The app works very well though!

#### The test file :-

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from '../renderer/App';

describe('App', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    render(<App />);
    const windowElem = screen.findByTestId('window');

    expect(windowElem).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

##### The log:-

```sh
 FAIL  src/__tests__/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    No such module was linked: electron_common_features

      at Object.getElectronBinding (node_modules/@electron/remote/dist/src/common/get-electron-binding.js:6:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@electron/remote/dist/src/common/module-names.js:44:41)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@electron/remote/dist/src/renderer/remote.js:7:24)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.665 s
Ran all test suites.
```

##### Versions from `package.json`:-

Not all packages are listed!!

```json
    "detect-port": "^1.3.0",
    "electron": "^16.0.5",
    "electron-builder": "22.13.1",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-notarize": "^1.1.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.5",
    "jest": "^27.4.5",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
    "7.css": "^0.5.0",
    "@electron/remote": "^2.0.1",
    "electron-debug": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.4.4",
    "electron-updater": "^4.6.4",
    "history": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "screenfull": "^6.0.1"

    // engines
    "node": ">=14.x",
    "npm": ">=7.x"
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same error, please let me if you find any fix. Thanks.

Comment: @AymenFezai not yet! But [I created an issue on GitHub (electron/remote#101)](https://github.com/electron/remote/issues/101) (not exactly this issue) and I think fixing that issue will maybe also fix these errors!

Comment: Were you able to find any fix for this?

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni if your still stuck on this, for my case, the problem is in "@electron/remote", so I called it inside a useEffect. 
It is a solution for the moment, till I find something better.
I am using "Nextron", btw.

Answer (score 0):

if your condition is similar with me, i have the solution after a lof of trials. Put the code below at the beginning of your code:

```
jest.mock('@electron/remote', () => ({ exec: jest.fn() }));
```

you can visit more detail to
https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/3295